# Escreva um programa para ler 3 valores inteiros (considere que não serão lidos valores iguais) e escrevê-los em ordem crescente. em JS

Tags: javascript

O que eu ja fiz...

```
var n1, n2, n3, rs, maior, menor, meio;

rs = require("readline-sync")
n1 = rs.questionInt("Digite o primeiro valor ")
n2 = rs.questionInt("Digite o segundo valor ")
n3 = rs.questionInt("Digite o terceiro valor ")
if ((n1 > n2) && (n1 > n3)) {
    maior = n1;
    if (n2 < n3) {
        meio = n3
        menor = n2
    }
    else   {
        meio = n2
        menor = n3
    }


}
else if ((n2 > n1) && (n2 > n3)) {
    maior = n2;
    if (n1 < n3) {
        meio = n3
        menor = n1   }
    else {   {
        meio = n1
        menor = n3
    }
}

}
console.log(menor, meio, maior)
```

> > **se digitar 8-4-1 ele mostra 1-4-8
> >     **já ao contrario não
> >
> > > **sem usar laço de repetição

Comment: Importante você [edit] seu post e explicar detalhadamente o problema, descrevendo o que tentou e onde está a dificuldade atual, de preferência com um [mcve]. Estudar a postagem disponível neste link pode fazer uma diferença muito positiva no seu aproveitamento do site: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70)

Comment: Luiz, o problema é essa frase "se digitar 8-4-1 ele mostra 1-4-8 já ao contrario não" deveria ser algo do tipo "se eu digitar um entrada desordenada, 8-4-1, funciona. Porém se eu digitar uma entrada já ordenada, 1-4-8, o algorítimo não funciona.". Somos um site de perguntas e respostas(Q&A), então a clareza da pergunta e muito importante para nós.

Answer (score 1):

> A pergunta é:
>   Você realmente sabe se o seu algorítimo funciona para todos os possíveis caso?

Ao fazer um algorítimo de ordenação puramente comparativo a primeira coisa que deve  consideração é quantidade de combinações que podem ser geradas pela quantidade de elementos na entrada.
Para descobrir esse número de combinações basta calcular o fatorial do número de elemento que serão ordenados, como são três elemento a serem ordenados então serão `3! = 6` diferentes combinações que a entrada poderá estar disposta:

1. menor, meio , maior
2. menor, maior, meio
3. meio , menor, maior
4. meio , maior, menor
5. maior, menor, meio
6. maior, meio, menor

A segunda coisa que deve considerar é se o seu algorítimo funciona em todos os casos.

Para efeito de testes construí uma array com os números 1, 2 e 3 que será usada para testar todas as possibilidades do algorítimo:

```
teste = [[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]];
```

Em seguida eu encapsulei o seu algorítimo em uma função para facilitar a testagem:

```
function ordenar(entrada){
  let maior, menor, meio;

  let n1 = entrada[0];
  let n2 = entrada[1];
  let n3 = entrada[2];

  if ((n1 > n2) && (n1 > n3)) {
    maior = n1;
    if (n2 < n3) {
        meio = n3
        menor = n2
    } else {
        meio = n2
        menor = n3
    }
  } else if ((n2 > n1) && (n2 > n3)) {
      maior = n2;
      if (n1 < n3) {
          meio = n3
          menor = n1   
      } else {   
          meio = n1
          menor = n3
      }
  }
  return [menor,meio,maior]
}
```

É o mesmo algorítimo da pergunta só que ao invés de receber a entrada pelo console ele vai receber por vez uma `array` de três elementos com entrada, simulando a entrada pelo console de três números.

Então criei uma função de testes que itera sobre as diferentes possíveis combinações não repetidas formadas pelos números 1, 2 e 3:

```
//Teste de sucesso do algorítimo de ordenação.
teste.forEach((caso) =>{
  //Obtem o resultado do algorítimo de ordenação para o caso a ser analisado.
  let resultado = ordenar(caso);
  console.log(`------------------------------`);
  console.log(`entrada: ${caso}`);
  console.log(`resultado: ${resultado}`);
  //Faz uma comparação superficial entre o resultado esperado e o resultado
  console.log(`teste ${JSON.stringify([1,2,3])==JSON.stringify(resultado)? 'APROVADO': 'REPROVADO'}`);
});
```

Então fiz o teste aqui https://repl.it/repls/LoneSoulfulMonad
Resultando:

```
------------------------------
entrada: 1,2,3
resultado: ,,
teste REPROVADO
------------------------------
entrada: 1,3,2
resultado: 1,2,3
teste APROVADO
------------------------------
entrada: 2,1,3
resultado: ,,
teste REPROVADO
------------------------------
entrada: 2,3,1
resultado: 1,2,3
teste APROVADO
------------------------------
entrada: 3,1,2
resultado: 1,2,3
teste APROVADO
------------------------------
entrada: 3,2,1
resultado: 1,2,3
teste APROVADO
```

Como pode ser visto o seu algorítimo falhou em dois casos:

```
------------------------------
entrada: 1,2,3
resultado: ,,
teste REPROVADO
------------------------------
entrada: 2,1,3
resultado: ,,
teste REPROVADO
```

O primeiro caso é o mais simples de resolver, é quando a entrada já vem ordenada `1,2,3` basta atribuir as variáveis `menor`, `meio` e `maior` os valores da entrada conforme estão dispostos:

```
//Solução para o caso da entrada já vier ordenada.
  let menor = n1 = entrada[0];
  let meio  = n2 = entrada[1];
  let maior = n3 = entrada[2];
```

O segundo caso em que o algorítimo falha é `2,1,3`. Falha porque a condição de teste para essa entrada não está presente no seu algorítimo que seria `(n1 > n2) && (n1 < n3)`.  Fazendo as mudanças no seu algorítimo:

```
function ordenar(entrada){
  //Caso da entrada já vier ordenada.
  let menor = n1 = entrada[0];
  let meio  = n2 = entrada[1];
  let maior = n3 = entrada[2];

  if (n1 > n2){
    if (n1 > n3) {
      maior = n1;
      if (n2 < n3) {
          meio = n3
          menor = n2
      } else {
          //meio = n2; <-- Se tornou redundante
          menor = n3
      }
    } else { //caso (n1 < n3)
      menor = n2
      meio = n1
    }
  } else if ((n1 < n2) && (n2 > n3)) {
      maior = n2;
      if (n1 < n3) {
          meio = n3
          //menor = n1  <-- Se tornou redundante
      } else {   
          meio = n1
          menor = n3
      }
  } 
  return [menor,meio,maior]
}
```

Então fiz esse teste: https://repl.it/repls/VisibleLemonchiffonForms
Que resultou:

```
------------------------------
entrada: 1,2,3
resultado: 1,2,3
teste APROVADO
------------------------------
entrada: 1,3,2
resultado: 1,2,3
teste APROVADO
------------------------------
entrada: 2,1,3
resultado: 1,2,3
teste APROVADO
------------------------------
entrada: 2,3,1
resultado: 1,2,3
teste APROVADO
------------------------------
entrada: 3,1,2
resultado: 1,2,3
teste APROVADO
------------------------------
entrada: 3,2,1
resultado: 1,2,3
teste APROVADO
```

---

Sinceramente eu acho que segundo os parâmetros dados você buscou o caminho mais difícil.

A maneira mais simples seria declarar uma array para receber as entradas e aplicar o método [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```
var n= new Array(3);

rs = require("readline-sync")
n[0] = rs.questionInt("Digite o primeiro valor ")
n[1] = rs.questionInt("Digite o segundo valor ")
n[2] = rs.questionInt("Digite o terceiro valor ")

n.sort();
console.log(n);
```

Se não quiser usar método `sort()` pode usar a [sintaxe de desestruturação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Atribuicao_via_desestruturacao) para permutar os elementos da array enquanto os testa:

```
var n= new Array(3);

rs = require("readline-sync")
n[0] = rs.questionInt("Digite o primeiro valor ")
n[1] = rs.questionInt("Digite o segundo valor ")
n[2] = rs.questionInt("Digite o terceiro valor ")

if (n[0] > n[1]) [n[0],n[1]] = [n[1],n[0]];
if (n[1] > n[2]) [n[1],n[2]] = [n[2],n[1]];
if (n[0] > n[1]) [n[0],n[1]] = [n[1],n[0]];

console.log(n);
```

Os testes desses dois últimos algorítimos: https://repl.it/repls/CompetentAdmiredEditors

Caso tenha curiosidade em conhecer métodos de ordenação mais elaborados [veja essa lista](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o) e pesquise aqui no site os nomes dos algorítimos contidos nessa lista.